# How to relate the muliple table in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the 5 tables. Thats are

### maintable

```
id int(11)=>primary key auto increment,
name varchar(255)
```

### subtable1

```
id int(11)=>primary key auto increment,
mainid int(11),
field1 varchar(255),
field2 varchar(255)
```

### subtable2

```
id int(11)=>primary key auto increment,
mainid int(11),
field3 varchar(255),
field4 varchar(255)
```

### subtable3

```
id int(11)=>primary key auto increment,
mainid int(11),
field5 varchar(255),
field6 varchar(255)
```

### subtable4

```
id int(11)=>primary key auto increment,
mainid int(11),
field7 varchar(255),
field8 varchar(255)
```

Here  mainid is the common for all the tables. i want to show all the table fields in one page... In that page we get the name as input ... each table contain around 5 lakh records..

How effectively i can write the query for above situation?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is select all fields from all tables without filtering by anything then yes its relatively simple to do with INNER JOINS.

For example ...

```
SELECT * FROM maintable INNER JOIN subtable1 ON subtable1.mainid = maintable.id INNER JOIN subtable2 ON subtable2.mainid = maintableid ...
```

etc

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  mmaintable.colnames,
  subtable1.colnames,
  subtable2.colnames,
  subtable3.colnames,
  subtable4.colnames
FROM maintable
  LEFT JOIN subtable1
    ON subtable1.mainid = maintable.id
  LEFT JOIN subtable2
    ON subtable2.mainid = maintable.id 
      LEFT JOIN subtable3
    ON subtable3.mainid = maintable.id 
      LEFT JOIN subtable4
    ON subtable4.mainid = maintable.id
```